# removing ?page=add_theme from the url

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

Lately I have been trying something and was trying to add a theme system like wordpress ( not creating a whole new wordpress ) just trying to implement their login.

I have this index.php file

```
<?php
    include('core/core.php');

    echo $_GET['id'];

    $currentTheme = getPageData() -> theme_selected;
    
    include("jtq-theme/" . $currentTheme . "/index.php");

?>
```

so this basically displays http://xxxxx/jtq-theme/default/index.php on the main page.
So now when a person goes to the about us page.

so index.php is the main file that displays everything.
and the about us page is being showing using the logic

http://xxxx/index.php?page=about_us

but I want the url to be

http://xxxx/about_us

and the file should be grabbed from
http://xxxx/jtq-theme/default/about_us.php

How should I write the .htaccess in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Add this rewrite rules to your htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}    "page=" [NC] 
RewriteRule (.*)  /$1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

It will change your request from `xxxx/index.php?page=about_us` to `xxxx/about_us`

**Update:**

For getting data in `about_us` page you should add a condition in your `index.php` file:

```
<?php
    include('core/core.php');

    echo $_GET['id'];

    $currentTheme = getPageData() -> theme_selected;

    $page = $_GET['page'];    
    if ($page == "about_us") {
        include("jtq-theme/" . $currentTheme . "/about_us.php");
    } else {
        include("jtq-theme/" . $currentTheme . "/index.php");
    }
    

?>
```

Comment: Hey @pejman thank you so much for replying. When I go to the url http://xxxx/about_us

it is not locating the about_us.php page in jtq-theme/default/about_us.php

Comment: What do you see in the browser?

Comment: Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Comment: @AhadAman Check the answer update

Comment: Still the error persists, http://xxxxxx/?page=about_us << this works fine.
http://xxxxx/about_us << but this gives 404 error

Comment: Try RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA] Instead of first 2 lines

Comment: Still not working.